# Can a large function that is only called once be inline?

Tags: c++, optimization

A friend wrote a function, about 300 lines of code, and asked me how to turn it to be inline.

I told him it's too big, and will result in instruction enflation. Then I thought, but he calls this function only once. So, there's no downside.

It feels wrong. Is it wrong?

Comment: Why not look at the resulting assembly instead of conjecturing?

Comment: There's nothing in the standard to say it can't. It all comes down to which compiler you are using and how aggressive it is at optimizing.

Comment: Please detail what compiler and compiler settings you are using.  This is very compiler specific and if you are expecting an answer that covers all situations that would be too broad.

Comment: No need to think about inline or not. The compiler will do its best and this is even better then your code :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gcc does this optimization. When a static function is only called once it gets inlined. It doesn't do this with external functions because it can't determine who calls the function.

You can check the assembler by going here:

https://gcc.godbolt.org/

First with an **extern** function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int test(int x);

int main() {
  int x = test(10);

  printf("%d\n", x);
}

int test(int x)
{
  volatile int y = x;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    y++;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    y++;

  return y;
}
```

The assembler output of main() with -O optimization as compiler flag:

```
main:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $10, %edi
        call    test(int)
        movl    %eax, %esi
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
        movl    $0, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

You can see that test is called and the return value in EAX is stored in $0.

Now make test static and observe that the call to test dissappears and the code is inlined.

Comment: Not fully true in times we have link time optimization. There is simply no need to think about inlining or not! Maybe the function get be inlined multiple times but with other constants from the caller. Many other scenarios possible...

Comment: It is not universally true that GCC inlines functions that are called once. As of GCC 11, there is an upper limit on the resulting function size. For all the details, see https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ipa-inline.c.

Answer (score 4):

A large function can be inline. **If** it is called only once, then there is no disadvantage (except for the possibility that you might start calling it more in future).

Whether the compiler actually optimizes the call (expands the function at call site), is another matter. If the function has internal linkage, then it is easy to prove that the function is called exactly once. If it has external linkage, then it is only possible with whole program optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Is shouldn't be inline in case if you will use this function twice, but if you will use it only once, then it can be inline.

Comment: Inlining is done by the compiler/optimizer. If the statistic says it is better to inline, he will inline. Don't think about the optimizer. This part of the compiler is better as you believe!